# Changing Visual Studio 2010 splash screen

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have seen how to change the splash screen on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vssetup/thread/ee69ebed-66e6-4e5b-88a2-5c242695eddc), however it does not seem to be working.

After looking around some more I stumbled upon a file called `vs000223.dat` which apparently contains a cached version of the splash screen and resides in two folders (`ProgramData` and `AppData`).

I have deleted both instances of the file and all that happens is that the default splash screen comes up without any text. This only happens the first time, though (until the `vs000223.dat` is recreated).

Any help would be highly appreciated!